# Group a Column based on Time Range

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, group-by

I have a view (in Oracle) like below which has joined from three tables:

```
Col1   Col2    Time
====   =====   =====
txt1   same0   10:50
txt2   same0   10:51
txt3   same0   16:30
txt4   same0   10:54
txt5   same1   15:15
txt6   same2   16:31
txt7   same3   08:05
txt8   same3   08:07
```

I want a query that group col2 data that has the time less than 5 minutes (for example) and count the rows that grouped together. So the query result should look like this:

```
Col1             Col2    Time                Count
====             =====   =====               =====
txt1,txt2,txt4   same0   10:50,10:51,10:54   3
txt3             same0   16:30               1
txt5             same1   15:15               1
txt6             same2   16:31               1
txt7,txt8        same3   08:05,08:07         2
```

*The `Time` column datatype is `DATE` but it is simplified here for better understanding.*

**Edit:**

In the situation below (from comments), the max `Count` of 5 is useful. For example:

```
Col1   Col2    Time
====   =====   =====
txt1   same0   10:50
txt2   same0   10:51
txt3   same0   10:52
txt4   same0   10:53
txt5   same0   10:54
txt6   same0   10:55
txt7   same0   10:56
```

It should be:

```
Col1                       Col2    Time                            Count
====                       =====   =====                           =====
txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4,txt5   same0   10:50,10:51,10:52,10:53,10:54   5
txt6,txt7                  same0   10:55,10:56                     2
```

Comment: What would the grouping be for 10:48,10:49,10:50, 10:51, 10:52, 10:53, 10:54?

Comment: also would 16:30 , 16:31 and 15:15 be grouped aswell? Like everything from 0-5 mins, all from 5.01 - 10 mins, all from 10.01 to 15 and all from 15-20 etc... ?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Nice tip, thanks. In the situation you've mentioned, I think the max count of 5 is good for that. So it should be 10:48,10:49,10:50,10:51,10:52 in one row, and 10:53, 10:54 in another row.

Comment: @JeremyC. No Jeremy. The range of time with the same col2 is considered. If you read the David comment, it should help you for better underestanding of the question. I don't know how to explain deeper, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/276c30/1)

If you want to group the values by 5 minute intervals (i.e 10:45-10:49, 10:50-10:54, 10:55-11:00, etc ) then you can do:

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( Col1, Col2, Time ) AS
          SELECT 'txt01', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:49', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt02', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:50', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt03', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:51', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt04', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:52', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt05', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:53', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt06', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt07', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:55', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt08', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 10:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt09', 'same0', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 16:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt10', 'same1', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 15:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt11', 'same2', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 16:31', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt12', 'same3', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 08:05', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'txt13', 'same3', TO_DATE( '2015-06-29 08:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( Col1, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Time ) AS Col1,
       Col2,
       LISTAGG( TO_CHAR( Time, 'HH24:MI' ), ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Time ) AS Time,
       COUNT(1) AS "Count"
FROM   TEST
GROUP BY
       Col2,
       TRUNC( Time ),
       FLOOR( ( TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( Time, 'HH24' ) ) * 60 + TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( Time, 'MI' ) ) ) / 5 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/276c30/1/0)**:

```
|                          COL1 |  COL2 |                          TIME | Count |
|-------------------------------|-------|-------------------------------|-------|
|                         txt01 | same0 |                         10:49 |     1 |
| txt02,txt03,txt04,txt05,txt06 | same0 | 10:50,10:51,10:52,10:53,10:54 |     5 |
|                   txt07,txt08 | same0 |                   10:55,10:56 |     2 |
|                         txt09 | same0 |                         16:30 |     1 |
|                         txt10 | same1 |                         15:15 |     1 |
|                         txt11 | same2 |                         16:31 |     1 |
|                   txt12,txt13 | same3 |                   08:05,08:07 |     2 |
```

If you want to have groups of up to 5 rows which are all in the same 5 minute period and can start from any time then you can use a pipelined function:

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE TEST_GROUP_OBJ AS OBJECT(
  Col1 VARCHAR2(54), -- 5 * Length of Col1 + 4
  Col2 VARCHAR2(10), -- Length of Col2
  Time VARCHAR2(29)  -- 5 * Length of 'HH:MI' + 4
)
/
CREATE TYPE TEST_GROUP_TAB AS TABLE OF TEST_GROUP_OBJ
/
CREATE FUNCTION getFiveMinuteGroupings
RETURN TEST_GROUP_TAB PIPELINED
AS
  TYPE TEST_TAB IS TABLE OF TEST%ROWTYPE;
  t_test_tab TEST_TAB;
  v_time     TEST.TIME%TYPE;
  v_grp      TEST_GROUP_OBJ := TEST_GROUP_OBJ( NULL, NULL, NULL );
  v_count    NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO t_test_tab
  FROM TEST
  ORDER BY Col2, Time;

  IF t_test_tab.COUNT = 0 THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  v_time     := t_test_tab(1).TIME;
  v_grp.COL1 := t_test_tab(1).COL1;
  v_grp.COL2 := t_test_tab(1).COL2;
  v_grp.TIME := TO_CHAR( t_test_tab(1).TIME, 'HH24:MI' );
  v_count    := 1;

  FOR i IN 2 .. t_test_tab.COUNT LOOP
    IF    t_test_tab(i).COL2 =  v_grp.COL2
      AND t_test_tab(i).TIME <= v_time + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
      AND v_count < 5
    THEN
      v_grp.COL1 := v_grp.COL1 || ',' || t_test_tab(i).COL1;
      v_grp.TIME := v_grp.TIME || ',' || TO_CHAR( t_test_tab(i).TIME, 'HH24:MI' );
      v_count    := v_count + 1;
    ELSE
      PIPE ROW( v_grp );
      v_time     := t_test_tab(i).TIME;
      v_grp.COL1 := t_test_tab(i).COL1;
      v_grp.COL2 := t_test_tab(i).COL2;
      v_grp.TIME := TO_CHAR( t_test_tab(i).TIME, 'HH24:MI' );
      v_count    := 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  PIPE ROW( v_grp );
END;
/
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( getFiveMinuteGroupings() )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/276c30/1/1)**:

```
|                          COL1 |  COL2 |                          TIME |
|-------------------------------|-------|-------------------------------|
| txt01,txt02,txt03,txt04,txt05 | same0 | 10:49,10:50,10:51,10:52,10:53 |
|             txt06,txt07,txt08 | same0 |             10:54,10:55,10:56 |
|                         txt09 | same0 |                         16:30 |
|                         txt10 | same1 |                         15:15 |
|                         txt11 | same2 |                         16:31 |
|                   txt12,txt13 | same3 |                   08:05,08:07 |
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Just one question. Is there a way to start from 10:49 to 10:53 and in another row 10:54 to 10:56? I mean starting from the time begins. Of course it is not important, I've just asked for better underestanding. And may need in some situation. Because in this way we have 3 rows of "same0" instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

This query gave me desired output:

```
select  
    listagg(col1, ', ') within group (order by col1) col1, col2, 
    listagg(to_char(ttime, 'hh24:mi'), ', ') within group (order by ttime) as ttime,
    count(1) cnt
  from (
    select col1, col2, ttime, trunc(ttime, 'dd') + floor(to_char(ttime,'sssss')/300)/288 tmp
      from test)
  group by col2, tmp
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7807c0/1)</sup>